# GREP: Find lines more than 12 characters excluding spaces

Tags: grep, sublimetext3

I am using a GREP search in [Sublime Text 3](https://www.sublimetext.com/). I want to find all lines that are more than 12 characters, excluding spaces.

**Example**

```
Mac and Cheese
Peanut Butter and Jelly Sandwich
```

In the above example, `Mac and Cheese` would not be found, because it's exactly 12 characters excluding spaces.

How would I do this?

I can use the following to find all lines that are more than 12 characters. But I am not sure how to exclude spaces:

```
(?<=.{13}).+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `(?<=.{13}).+` will assert what is on the left is 13 characters and the dot will also match a space. Then it will match any char except a whitespace 1+ times.

You could match horizontal whitespace chars and repeat 13 or more times matching a non whitespace char for example `\S` (or specify what you would allow to match) followed by 0+ horizontal whitespace chars.

```
^\h*(?:\S\h*){13,}$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\h*` Match 0+ times a horizontal whitespace char
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\S\h*` Match non whitespace char, then 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `){13,}` Close group and repeat 13+ times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yCwrVt/1)