# SUBLIME & GREP: Conduct a GREP search, but exclude lines that are in all in capitals

Tags: grep, sublimetext3

I am using a GREP search in the find function of Sublime Text 3. I want to find all lines that are more than 12 characters, excluding spaces. As discussed in this [Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57628730/grep-find-lines-more-than-12-characters-excluding-spaces/57628789#57628789), the way to do this is with the following command:

`^\h*(?:\S\h*){13,}$`

But I also want the GREP search to exclude all lines that are written in all caps, when it is conducting the above search.

Example:

```
FAVORITE FOODS OF AMERICA 
Mac and Cheese
Peanut Butter and Jelly Sandwich
```

- In the above example, `Mac and Cheese` *would not* be found, because
  it's exactly 12 characters excluding spaces.
- `FAVORITE FOODS OF AMERICA` would also *not* be found because although it's more than 12 characters, it is a line that is written in all caps.
- Only `Peanut Butter and Jelly Sandwich` ***would*** be found, because it's more than 12 characters and although it has capital letters, the line is not written in all caps.

How would I do this? Googling around I can find Grep commands that exclude lines that contain at least one capital letter, but not lines that are only in all caps.

Note: I am using the Grep option in Sublime's Find function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead asserting what is on the right is not only uppercase chars with possible horizontal whitespace chars.

```
^(?![A-Z\h]+$)\h*(?:\S\h*){13,}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hhab4d/1)

Comment: `grep` generally does not support lookaheads. Try `grep-P` if you have it; but it's not portable.

Comment: Based on the question I think @big_smile is actually doing a `Find` in Sublime (i.e. not actually using `grep` per se) in which case the regex here works based on the sample input above. For actual grep, perhaps a `pipe` of `grep | grep -v` to redact away the uppercase matches would be more portable than `grep -P`?

Comment: @The fourth bird. This doesn't seem to work in the grep option in Sublime's Find. It just highlights all the files that have lines that are longer than 12 characters but also are in all capitals (I want it to ignore the lines that are all in capitals). Are there any tricks to getting it to work in Sublime's Find? Thanks! (I have updated the question to make it clear that it Sublime's function, as I didn't realize there was a difference).

Comment: @big_smile this regex works for me (i.e. finding only the PB&J text from your question but not the other two lines) if I use a `Find`; are you saying that it is also matching on `FAVORITE FOODS OF AMERICA` as well?

Comment: @big_smile This is a quite verbose version without lookarounds https://regex101.com/r/zZtFYx/1/

Comment: @Thefourthbird I've found the issue. The grep works, but if a line that is in all caps has punctuation (e.g. `AMERICA'S FAVORITE "FOODS"`) it will be matched. Is there any way to exclude punctuation. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @big_smile You could add the punctuations to the negated character class https://regex101.com/r/C6rOtc/1